# Replace characters in relative linespan

Tags: substitute, line-numbers, multiple-lines, range

I know that I can replace characters in a linespan via something to the effect of `:300,305s/foo/bar/g`
But when I'm deep in the code, and I know that I just want to replace in the next five lines, I'm wasting both keystrokes and time looking up the line numbers by setting absolute line numbers.

Is there a way to perform a substitute based on a *relative* linespan, something to the effect of (trigger warning: pseudo-vim) `:+5s/foo/bar/g`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually figured it out a few minutes later: define a range based on current location `.` and relative line number `+{}` or `-{}`, e.g. `:.,+5s/foo/bar/g`.

I'll leave the question up anyway for the sake of anyone else who might want to know how to do that.

Comment: See `:help [range]` for more fun things :) You can leave off the `.` in `:,+5` if that makes typing easier.

Comment: another way is `v5j:` to automatically populate the range, which is roughly the same amount of typing

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using Visual Line mode for this.

1. Enter Visual Line mode with `V`.  This will highlight the current line.
2. `5j` to also select the next five lines.
3. Enter command line mode with `:` and the command line will appear like:
   `:'<,'>`
   which is the range notation for the visual selection.
4. Add your substitution command after the range.

Comment: strictly speaking, any `:` command you run from any visual mode is linewise and is populated with the range `:'<,'>`, so you can save yourself a shift with `v5j:`

Comment: I doubted this initially, but you're exactly right because ranges work line-by-line.